# rails 3.2.8 validation errors not showing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Can’t figure out how to get validation errors to show in create or edit views.

In my model I have:

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

 belongs_to :organization

   validates_presence_of :first_name,  :message => "First name can't be blank"
   validates_presence_of :last_name,  :message => "Last name can't be blank"
```

In my Controller I have

```
def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
        if @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
       redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end
```

In my view I have

```
<div>
<%= form_for(:person, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @person.id}) do |f| %>
<%= f.errors %>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <div>
    <%= submit_tag("Update Person") %>
       </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

When I test validations in my browser by leaving first name field blank, it doesn’t save the record and redirects to edit but does not display any validation errors. However, when I try it out in the console using:

```
f = Person.find(1)
#returns record
f.first_name = “”
#returns “”
f.save
#returns false 
f.errors
#returns @message = (:first_name => [“First name can't be blank”])
```

so it works in the console but not the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the method to show errors is `<%= f.error_messages %>` or `<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %> <li><%= msg %></li> <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I get "undefined method `error_messages' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x417a800>" when i use f.error_messages and "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass" when i use the second way.

Comment: And if you trade `@person` instead of `:person`

Comment: And remember that its `@person` no `@post` as my last comment shows

Comment: no, that didn't work either. I got the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong way to show error messages. It is `<%= f.error_messages %>` and not `<%= f.errors %>`. Take a look at this link 
 [rails_rendering_errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of lynda.com and K. Skoglund I figured out how to fix the errors. First I created a partial to handle the error messages

```
<% if object && object.errors.size > 0 %>
    <div>
        <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.size, "error") %> 
        prohibited this record from being saved</h2>
        <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
        <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
     <% end %>
```

Then I created a helper method to call in the forms

```
def error_messages_for (object)
  render(:partial => 'shared/error_messages', 
  :locals => {:object => object})
end
```

Lastly, I added the helper method to the top of a form partial that I created to use for both the edit and new templates:

```
<%= error_messages_for(@person) %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

While that doesn't directly answer your question I highly recommend to stop writing an 'agile development with rails' type of code. Get familiar with excelent gems such as:

- decent_exposure
- simple_form
- haml-rails

and stop writing tons of boilerplate code to do simple things.